# Hibernate example criteria doesnt work with the query cache?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

Hibernate 3.6.8.Final

Does anyone know how example criterias in hibernate work with the query cache. In my case, as soon as I enable caching on a criteria it stops working (never returns a result regardless of db contents).

Cache definitions

```
<cache name="DimensionQueryCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="100000"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="true" />

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="100000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    overflowToDisk="false" />
```

Hibernate config :

```
<persistence-unit name="sqlServerPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <properties>
        <!-- See Hibernate's Environment class. -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dbo"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="2" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
        <!-- If we ever switch to a clustered L2 cache, set hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries to true -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="false" />
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="META-INF/ehcache-hibernate.xml" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" value="META-INF/ehcache-hibernate.xml" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Query :-

```
Dimension existingCandidate= jpaTemplate.execute(new JpaCallback() {
        public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
            Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
            Dimension existingCandidate = (Dimension) session.createCriteria(dimension.getClass()).setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("DimensionQueryCache").add(Example.create(dimension)).uniqueResult(); 
            return existingCandidate;
        }
    });
```

Like I said, if I remove setCacheable and the query region it works fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to name your SessionFactory on your Hibernate configuration file. It seems there is a problem on later versions of Hibernate on handling cache replication via RMI (see at https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6162).

Comment: Initially seems not to work. Seems sensible though so i'll investigate further later on.